# Can't change selection highlight color MS Visio Pro 2019

Tags: colors, microsoft-visio, selection, highlighting

I have Visio Pro *2019* installed on a Windows 10 machine with Office Pro 2016 for all other MS products. By default it is dark blue and nearly invisible when selecting black stencils, lines, etc.

Following the instructions from the *Change selection highlight color in Microsoft Visio Pro 2016 x64* post, I navigate to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Visio\Colors and change the value in ColorManySelect to 255 100 255 per the instructions. The registry also has a path to \Office\15\Visio\Colors, so I changed the ColorManySelect value there too. When selecting one or more items, the highlight color is still blue.

No sure where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Was Visio closed when you edited the registry settings? You might find that settings are rewritten when Visio closes and only reads settings when Visio starts.

Comment: Hi, the new values have been retained in the registry. Many reboots & loading Visio since original changes were made.